# Python 3 - count letters/words in text document/quick question

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to know how to achieve the same result as the code I listed below without using any collections, or for someone to explain what goes on inside the Counter collection (in code or in a way that isn't confusing) since I can't seem to find it anywhere. This code is meant to read a text file called juliet.txt. I am trying to make it count the amount of letters and spaces inside the document and then print it as a result.

Code:

```
from collections import Counter
   text = open('juliet.txt', 'r').read()
   letters = 0
   counter = Counter(text)
   spacesAndNewlines = counter[' '] + counter['\n']

    while letters < len(text):
        print (text[letters])
        letters += 1
    while letters == len(text):
    print (letters)
    letters += 1
    print (spacesAndNewlines)
```

Comment: You should probably consider reading the official documentation about `Counter`, it comes with thorough examples: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a homework question to me, in which case you won't get any benefit from me answering you.

```
letters = {}
with open('juliet.txt') as fh:
   data = fh.read()
for char in data:
   if char in letters:
       letters[char] = 1
    else:
        letters[char] += 1
print(letters)
```

This uses a standard dictionary - normally I would use a `defaultdict` but for some weird reason you don't like `collections`. With the `defaultdict` you wouldn't need to do the laborious test to see if the `char` is already in the dictionary.